# Running NPM on remote linked folder is causing EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

Let me describe my dev.

**Platform:**

I'm using Macbook Pro with High Sierra.
For development purposes, I installed `virtualbox` and all `dev. related server apps` are inside of it (like apache,postgresql,mongodb,nodejs etc.)

I'm keeping files on Macbook disk and Ubuntu has a symbolic link to that folder over sshfs.

My home folder on Macbook pro: `/home/sam/Development`

On Ubuntu there's a symbolic link to Macbook Development folder. Meanwhile folder of Ubuntu: `/home/admcomft/public_html` linked to `/home/sam/Development` with this command:

> sshfs -o allow_other -o cache=no -o uid=$(id -u) -o gid=$(id -g)
>   sam@192.168.56.1:/Users/sam/Development/ public_html/

The apache server is working fine with this relations. So I can be able to use my local environment on Macbook. But on `nodeJS` part, I'm getting errors when I tried to install `npm` packages.

### How can the CLI team reproduce the problem?

On Ubuntu I'm running this command:

`npm install mongoose`

on the folder: `/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube`

and it's producing this error:

> npm ERR! path /home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall chown
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, chown '/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300'
>   npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, chown '/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300'
>   npm ERR!   cause:
>   npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, chown '/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300'
>   npm ERR!      errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!      syscall: 'chown',
>   npm ERR!      path: '/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300' },
>   npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, chown \'/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'chown',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/home/admcomft/public_html/adMingle_v1.5/_youtube/node_modules/mquery/node_modules/debug/package.json.813517300',
>   npm ERR!   parent: 'mquery' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Even if I run it with `sudo`, nothing change.

But I'm be able to run it with `-g` parameter, but after global installation, my `nodeapp` still doesn't recognise that `npm` module and still saying that

> Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'

#### supporting information:

- `npm -v` prints: 5.6.0
- `node -v` prints: v8.2.1
- `npm config get registry` prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/
- Windows, OS X/macOS, or Linux?: OS X with Ubuntu (Ubuntu on virtual machine)

any thoughts?

Comment: Try following [this thread](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/issues/195)

Comment: I applied all of those but didn't help. I found a workaround for it, later on will add here